# Android Architecture Blueprints [todo-mvp-dagger] @ActivityScoped, @FragmentScoped

Tags: android, annotations, dagger-2, dagger

Looking at [https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-dagger/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksFragment.java](http://android-architecture/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/statistics/StatisticsFragment.java):

```
@ActivityScoped
public class TasksFragment extends DaggerFragment implements TasksContract.View {
```

and https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-dagger/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksModule.java:

```
@Module
public abstract class TasksModule {
    @FragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract TasksFragment tasksFragment();
```

1. Why @ActivityScoped is applied directly to TaskFragment? Should not be applied to taskFragment method, in the TaskModule?
2. Why @ActivityScoped and @FragmentScoped are used at the same time in the same fragment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because the fragment scope needs to know if it is inserted in activityscope the code generation for scoping is for reducing the memory footprint. This way activity and fragment can share memory.